# Where to find old alpha version of WordPress (WordPress 4.1-alpha-20141016)?

Tags: wordpress

I've inherited a WordPress site built with the following version (from wp-includes/version.php):

WordPress 4.1-alpha-20141016

I can't find this version anywhere. I need it so I can compare it to the prod site and see if the previous team made any changes to WP core files.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

For anyone interested, here's what I did:

- Cloned https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress:

`git clone https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress`

- Checked out the git tag closest to my version:

`git checkout 4.1`

- Checked the history of wp-includes/version.php:

`git log -- wp-includes/version.php`

- Found a commit on October 16th 2014 (the date of my alpha build). Checked out that commit:

`git checkout [commit_id]`

- Verified in wp-includes/version.php that the version # was the same as my alpha build.